# How to run multiple select query from same table with limit 0, 1 and combine all the result

Tags: mysql, database

I need to query out the data from same table with different where condition.

Like shown below in the query, i need to execute 2 select query from the same table and then combine the result into one.

```
SELECT Username, AddTime
FROM Table1
WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime>="2019-07-11 13:30:00" AND Username="Test1"
LIMIT 0, 1

SELECT Username, AddTime
FROM Table1
WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime>="2019-07-11 13:40:00" AND Username="Test2"
LIMIT 0, 1
```

i need to combine the result from both queries into one single result. so basically if i have lets say 5 such queries then i need to get the result whose number of rows will be equal to 5.

i could also use loop and query the statement each time but this will need to create lots of sql connection. is it possible to achieve this in one single DB Connection?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union query here:

```
(SELECT Username, AddTime
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-11 13:30:00' AND Username = 'Test1'
 LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Username, AddTime
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime >= '2019-07-11 13:40:00' AND Username = 'Test2'
 LIMIT 1);
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, there also might be a way to use a single query with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: I tried using UNION ALL before but got error. I didn't write it inside () and also i set LIMIT 0, 1 

your worked exactly the way i wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get two row with same condition for different username so you can use `IN`

```
SELECT Username, AddTime
FROM Table1
WHERE Type = 3 AND AddTime>="2019-07-11 13:40:00" AND Username IN ("Test1","Test2");
```

Comment: no i cannot use IN because for every username i need to have different AddTime
(Username = test1 Addtime = AddTime1)
(Username = test2 Addtime = Addtime2)